# codeigniter php photo gallery previos and next button

Tags: codeigniter

i have created photo gallery in codeigniter php, I have added previous and next button by using this code

```
$next = $this->uri->segment(3)+1;
previous = $this->uri->segment(3)-1;
```

The problem with the above approach is if next few id's are broken gallery terminates. Is there an easy solution for this ? i want photos to end when related gallery pictures ends, and it continues to play even if id's are missing or that id is taken by another category.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the [Pagination Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html) in Code Igniter,

If we could see some more of your code we could help...